=TODAY() changing previous days date
I want to have excel automatically put todays date into a cell which works with =TODAY(). But when I come to the spreadsheet the next day to add more data, all the cells from the previous day change which I don't want to.
Is there any other way to do the date other than manually entering the date.

Not without some VBA, or a lookup sheet which you update with a macro when closing the sheet (also, VBA)
